# Cakephp relationships not working

Tags: php, cakephp

I can't seem to find why this doesn't work. I know it's vague, but it's really all there is to say. Checking /posts I can't add the author. (Yes, I added one on /users)

Database tables: 
users:

```
id  int(11)
username    varchar(50)
password    varchar(50)
created     datetime
modified    datetime
```

posts:

```
id  int(11)
title   varchar(50)
body    text
created datetime
modified    datetime
user_id int(11)
```

Models
User:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'User';
    var $hasMany = 'Post';
}
```

Post:

```
class Post extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Post';
    var $belongsTo = 'User';
}
```

Controllers both scaffold.

Comment: whats the url your are accessing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up not being any of the code, as what I had was already correct. (Although, Neeraj Swarnkar was also correct)

The problem was my naming of the Models. They should be named as:

post.php 
and
user.php

Answer (score 0):

I think Your table is fine.. you have to modify your model..

like this :-

MOdels :-
USER:-

```
class User extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'User';

 var $hasMany = array('Post' => array('className' => 'Post'));
}
```

POST:-

```
class Post extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Post';

var $belongsTo = array('User' => array('className' => 'User'));
}
```

You can also give

```
var $hasMany = array(
        'Post' => array(
            'className' => 'Post',
            'foreignKey' => 'post_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
```

this will work definetly..